# Directory creation when user is in specific group

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

I was trying following task, to create a dir if user is a part of hdfsuser group

```
- include_vars: ../../security/vars/main.yml 

- name: create user tmp dir /srv/tmp/$USER on gateway
  file: path=/srv/tmp/{{ item.name }} owner={{ item.name }} group={{ item.name }} mode=0755 state=directory
  when: "'hdfsuser' in {{ item.groups }}"
  with_items: ssh_users #this is coming from - include_vars: ../../security/vars/main.yml 
  tags:
    - hadoop
```

But getting this error :

```
fatal: [hadoop-client001.dev.abc.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check ''hdfsuser' in {{ item.groups }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'string'. String: {% if 'hdfsuser' in [u'users'] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/xyz/ansible/roles/luigi/tasks/main.yml': line 81, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: create user tmp dir /srv/tmp/$USER on gateway\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Anyone knows a workaround for this ?

Comment: Try it without the braces around item.groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The when condition already is interpreted as a Jinja2 expression and therefore the braces are not required.

```
when: "'hdfsuser' in item.groups"
```